# Heightmap Generation using Perlin Noise returns black bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, generator, perlin-noise, heightmap

i'm making a Heightmap Generator using Perlin Noise, as the title says.

i've used a pseudocode from this site -> http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm

and turned in to C# code. so far i've done all the variable type assignment and the code gives an output. unfortunately my output looks like this -> [image]

as you can see, the right and bottom edges have a slight gradiant from black to white, but everything else is black.

here is my c# source ->

```
    private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        persistence = float.Parse( textBox4.Text );
        NumberOfOctaves = Int32.Parse( textBox5.Text );

        int width = Int32.Parse( textBox1.Text );
        int height = Int32.Parse( textBox2.Text );
        float zoom = float.Parse( textBox3.Text );

        generate( width, height, zoom );
    }

    public float Noise( int x, int y ) {
        long n = x + ( y * 57 );
        n = ( long )Math.Pow( ( n << 13 ), n );
        return ( float )( 1.0 - ( ( n * ( n * n * 15731 + 789221 ) + 1376312589 ) & 0x7fffffff ) / 1073741824.0 );
    }

    public float SmoothNoise( float x, float y ) {
        float corners = ( Noise((int) (x-1), (int) (y-1)) + Noise((int) (x+1), (int) (y-1)) + Noise((int) (x-1), (int) (y+1)) + Noise((int) (x+1), (int) (y+1)) ) / 16;
        float sides   = ( Noise((int) (x-1), (int) y) + Noise((int) (x+1), (int) y) + Noise((int) x, (int) (y-1)) + Noise((int) x, (int) (y+1)) ) /  8 ;
        float center  =  Noise( (int)x, (int)y ) / 4;
        return corners + sides + center;
    }

    public float CosineInterpolate( float a, float b, float x ) {
        double ft = x * 3.1415927;
        double f = ( 1 - Math.Cos( ft ) ) * 0.5;

        return (float)( ( a * ( 1 - f ) ) + (b * f) );
    }

    public float InterpolatedNoise( float x, float y ) {
        // MessageBox.Show( x.ToString() );
        int intX = ( int )x;
        float fractX = x - intX;

        int intY    = ( int ) y;
        float fractY = y - intY;

        float v1 = SmoothNoise(intX,     intY);
        float v2 = SmoothNoise(intX + 1, intY);
        float v3 = SmoothNoise(intX,     intY + 1);
        float v4 = SmoothNoise(intX + 1, intY + 1);

        float i1 = CosineInterpolate(v1 , v2 , fractX);
        float i2 = CosineInterpolate(v3 , v4 , fractX);

        // MessageBox.Show( intX + "\n" + intY + "\n" + fractX + "\n" + fractY + "\n" + v1 + "\n" + v2 + "\n" + v3 + "\n" + v4 + "\n" + i1 + "\n" + i2 + "\n" + CosineInterpolate( i1, i2, fractY ) );

        return CosineInterpolate(i1 , i2 , fractY);
    }

    public float PerlinNoise2D( float x, float y ) {
        float total = 0;
        float p = persistence;
        int n = NumberOfOctaves;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
            int frequency = (int)Math.Pow( 2, i );
            // MessageBox.Show( Math.Pow( 2, i ).ToString() );
            float amplitude = ( int )Math.Pow( p, i );
            total = total + InterpolatedNoise(x * frequency, y * frequency) * amplitude;
        }
        return total;
    }

    private void generate( int sizeX, int sizeY, float zoom ) {
        int zoomX = (int)( sizeX * zoom );
        int zoomY = (int)( sizeY * zoom );

        float max = int.MinValue;
        float min = int.MaxValue;

        float[,] nmap = new float[zoomX,zoomY];

        Bitmap heightMap = new Bitmap(zoomX,zoomY);

        for (int x=0; x<zoomX; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<zoomY; y++) {
                // MessageBox.Show( PerlinNoise2D( x / zoom, y / zoom ).ToString() );

                nmap[x,y] = PerlinNoise2D(x/zoom,y/zoom);
                max = (max < nmap[x,y]) ? nmap[x,y] : max;
                min = (min > nmap[x,y]) ? nmap[x,y] : min;
            }
        }

        max = max-min;

        for (int x=0; x<zoomX;x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<zoomY;y++) {
                int calc = (int) ( (nmap[x,y] - min) / max );
                heightMap.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(calc,calc,calc));
            }
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = heightMap;
    }
```

also i could upload the visual studio solution in a zip if anyone want's to.

so far now i've found out that something is wrong with the Noise() function, because it returns -0,281... the most time. it should return floating point numbers between -1.0 and 1.0.
i've tryed it with other random functions, but the output ooks the same every time.

i hope you guys can help me out, and thx for anny suggestions.

Comment: I'm guessing they meant 0x7fffffff. That said, why don't you try using C#'s built-in Random class instead?

Comment: i've also tryed it with 0x7fffffff, but the result is the same.
as i know, all the build in random classes in pretty much every programing languages are not 100% random at the max & min values...
the values in between min & max, are generatet much oftener then the values near the min & max...

Comment: Ace, that is a curious thing - have you been able to verify it? Of course no deterministic function will be 100% random, but if your problem is that your pseudorandom function is broken, it seems reasonable to first try the built-in one before writing your own replacement.

Answer (score 2):

I have found two issues in code.

First, you incorrectly interpreted `^` symbol as a power function 
in original source code, while it is a xor operation. So line

```
n = ( long )Math.Pow( ( n << 13 ), n );
```

Should be

```
n = ( long )(( n << 13 ) ^ n);
```

Second, when creating color pixel from noise value, your noise is in range 0..1, and color value should be in range 0..255, so line

```
int calc = (int) ( (nmap[x,y] - min) / max );
```

Should be

```
int calc = (int) (( (nmap[x,y] - min) / max ) * 255);
```

Full working (console) sample here: http://ideone.com/RGVf8J